# AngularJS directive using a service as its scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple view problem that I may have made more difficult by trying to create my first directive in Angular. I have this service that returns an array of user roles for the current user. Many users are only going to have the user role. With that in mind I don't want to display anything on their profile page. However, some people like myself will have User and Admin roles. So on the profile page I would like to display a drop down to change the current role.

I thought I'd create a directive that did a check basically

> if user.roles.length != 1 then show drop down else remove the element from the dom.

Like I said before I have never created a directive before and they seem like the right way to go but I am not getting the result I would like.

I have this:

```
app.directive('selector', function (SessionState, $compile) {
    return {
        priority: 100000,
        scope: false,
        compile: function (element, attr, linker) {

            var data = SessionState.User.Data.roles;

            var multiRoleView = '<p>Active Role:</p><select ng-model="State.User.activeRole" ng-options="role for role in data"></select>';

            if (data.length != 1) {
                element.html(multiRoleView).show();
                $compile(element.contents());
            } else {
                element.children.remove();
                element.remove();
            }

            return function linkFn() {
                /* Optional */
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This will render the html correctly depending on if that user should see it, but for admins it doesn't display any roles because I am assuming my data variable is never being used.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to post a bad question but with some fiddling around and reading the documentation for $compile I found that by setting the scope variable to true. I could simply use the parents scope and that made everything very easy.

The completed and correct code:

Live link: https://app.baileysproject.com

Set scope to true, uses parents scope.
Removed the element.children.remove(), throws errors.

```
app.directive('selector', function (SessionState, $compile) {
return {
    priority: 100000,
    scope: true,
    compile: function (element, attr, linker) {



        var multiRoleView = '<p>Active Role:</p><select ng-model="State.User.activeRole" ng-options="role for role in State.User.Data.roles"></select>';

        if (data.length != 1) {
            element.html(multiRoleView).show();
            $compile(element.contents());
        } else {
            element.remove();
        }

        return function linkFn() {
            /* Optional */
        }
    }
}
});
```